# asus 1001PXD keyboard/tiouchpad issue

Tags: windows-7, eee-pc

I have a asus 1001PXD running Windows 7 starter. After I login, the keyboard and touchpad are disabled. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are they listed in device manager?